# Checkbox, se desmarca al hacer click en un LinkButton; y no aparece como marcado en el lado del servidor (.aspx.vb)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp, visual

luego de marcar un checkbox (control de servidor) que se encuentra dentro de un gridview;  y posteriormente hacer clic en un botón que está fuera del gridview; intento recorrer los datos de dicho gridview en el lado del servidor (.aspx.vb); pero los checkbox aparecen desmarcados.

**NOTA:** Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET(.aspx) y Visual Basic (.aspx.vb)

*Adicionalmente también intenté leer el checkbox dentro de un gridview (evento rowcommand) y tampoco lee el valor marcado.*

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: Lectura recomendada:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su pregunta no está clara a mi.  Quiere recorrer los datos durante el evento POST o cuando se hace clique a un botón?

Tengo un form con (con otras cosas) un GridView con un checkbox y un botón para guardar.  Aquí está el código del botón de guardar.  Le ayuda?

```
Protected Sub btnApprove_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnApprove.Click
    For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.gvBill.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If (CType(row.FindControl("cbAccept"), CheckBox).Checked = True) Then
            ' Añadir los datos al base de datos
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Listo ya lo resolví, el problema que se desmarcaba el checkbox, era porque había otros botones que estaban haciendo PostBack antes de llegar al evento click del botón guardar. Muchas gracias Duston por tu apoyo.